# Is there any way to find out what javascript is affecting what element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've got some elements in the DOM that are being made visible by some javascript, but I can't find what javascript is affecting those elements? Like you can use firebug/chrome to find out what css is affecting the elements.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to find out which js code made changes on an element in the past.

To find out events connected to DOM elements you can use http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but it was the answer I was expecting. Thanks.